# Relaxed optimization problems

Tags: optimization

The original problem is 
\begin{align}
\min & f(x) \tag{1}\\
\text{s.t.} & \text{constraint 1}  \tag{2}\\
& \text{constraint 2} \tag{3}\\
\end{align}
However, it is very hard to deal with constraint 2. Therefore, I just solve the objective function f(x) only with constraint 1, and I get the optimal solution $x^*$. Coincidentally, $x^*$ also satisfies the constraint 2. Does it mean that $x^*$ is also the optimal solution of the original problem?

Answer (score 1):

Does $x^*$ satisfy the constraints?  Yes, you said so.

Can any other $x$ that satisfies the constraints give you a better objective value?  No, because $x^*$ is optimal for constraint (1).

So ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the  minimum of $f(x)$ for constraint1 satisfies constraint 2, you can see that  any other value of $f(x)$ less than the value  so obtained will not lie within in the  first constraint.